Send message to ActiveMQ Classic via Rest API with properties from Oracle
I can send a message from Oracle UTL_HTTP to ActiveMQ Classic using Rest API, but how can I add some properties to my message ?
myMessage := 'some text ....';
req := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST(lc_baseurl, method=>'POST');
UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(req, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0');
UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(req, 'content-type', 'application/json');
utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Length', length(myMessage));
utl_http.set_header(req, 'Authorization', 'Basic ....');
utl_http.set_header(req, 'APPLICATION_SOURCE', 'mySource');
UTL_HTTP.WRITE_TEXT (req, myMessage);
resp := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(req);

but I cannot see anywhere in the headers or the properties of the message my 'APPLICATION_SOURCE' value. I verified in the amq web console and with some tools like JMSToolbox. I can see the system headers that AMQ has set (jmsmessageID, jmsexpiration ... ) but not mine. And the "Properties" attribute is empty as well.


I verified in the amq web console and with some tools like JMSToolbox. I can see the system headers that AMQ has set (jmsmessageID, jmsexpiration ... ) but not mine. And the "Properties" attribute is empty as well

Finally I found the answser : thoses message headers have to be set as URL parameters, not HTTP headers. In my example :
http_req := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST(url => 'http://....:8161/api/message/MyQUEUE?type=queue&APPLICATION_SOURCE=GNX',METHOD => 'POST');
